# Copying files from one folder to another using vba

Tags: excel, vba, file, directory

There are some similar posts about this topic, I know. However, I have a code which is different than all codes I have seen here (when talking about this subject).

The error I am receiving is saying that the file couldn't be found. But that's kind of impossible, since I am searching for the file in the same folder I am using as SOURCE in fso.CopyFile.

So I have to fix this error and, if possible, I would like to copy the file to another folder and change the name. For example, if I have the file "Excel.xls", I would like to copy with the name "Excel_old.xls", is that possible using the code below or is it too hard that it's not worth?

This is the code:

```
Sub CopyFiles()
'Macro to copy all files modified yesterday

Dim n As String, msg As String, d As Date
Dim fso As Object

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fils = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\Desktop\Files\").Files

'Verify all files in the folder, check the modification date and then copy 
'to another folder (named Old)
For Each fil In fils
    n = fil.Name
    d = fil.DateLastModified
    If d >= Date - 1 Then
        file = n
        'The following line is where the error occurs
        fso.CopyFile "C:\Users\Desktop\Files\file", "C:\Users\Desktop\Files\Old\file"

    End If
Next fil

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `fso.CopyFile "C:\Users\Desktop\Files\file", "C:\Users\Desktop\Files\Old\file"` is not a file... It's just a string to a dummy file from the looks of it.

If instead the line was

`fso.CopyFile fil.Path, "C:\Users\Desktop\Files\Old\" & fil.name`... that might work.

Updated to add:

I just attempted the following using (subbing computer username for  below) and had success moving everything into a new folder:

```
Sub test()
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim fsoFiles As Files
    Dim fil As File

    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Set fils = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\<MY USERNAME>\Desktop\").Files

    For Each fil In fils
        n = fil.Name
        d = fil.DateLastModified
        fso.CopyFile fil.Path, fil.ParentFolder & "\test\" & fil.Name

    Next fil
End Sub
```

The only difference here is that I used fil.ParentFolder to get my Desktop and then tossed it into a new folder I created on my desktop (prior to running the script) named "test".

Comment: that's right. But there is a typo, after `fso.CopyFile` it should be either `file` or `fil.name` according to OP's code.

Comment: Yep.. should have been `fil.path` not `fil.name`. My apologies. I guess I'm a bit rusty with fso.

Comment: Used `fso.CopyFile fil.Path, "C:\Users\Desktop\Files\file", "C:\Users\Desktop\Files\Old\file"` and got the same error, Type Mismatch. I also tried `fso.CopyFile fil.Path, "C:\Users\Desktop\Files\file", "C:\Users\Desktop\Files\Old\"` and still getting error 13

Comment: Shouldn't it be: "C:\Users\Desktop\Files\" & file, "C:\Users\Desktop\Files\Old\" & file

Comment: Tried, same error again, I'm searching but I'm really struggling

Comment: Estraka, that would make more sense since this is in a loop. Otherwise the Destination would be overwritten every time a new file is found that passes the If statement. fso.CopyFile only takes two arguments, dekio, both are a string. The Source and the Destination both of which should be the path and full file name.

Comment: I just attempted this myself making a Tools>>Reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime so I could get tooltips and autocompletion from my VBE. Everything worked as I anticipated it would. (I didn't use the variables `n` and `d` but figured I would include them for fun. The code I used was added to my answer.

Comment: Let me see if I got it, because I'm not so clever with these things I write very simple codes and I don't actually understand how to work with fso for example. If I check the box Microsoft Scripting Runtime, I get tips in writing codes? Do you have any tip so I can improve my understand in vba and its objects for example? Thank you so much for all the help here!

Answer (score 0):

For moving all files in a folder:

```
Sub MoveFiles()

Dim MyFile As String

MyFile = Dir("C:\AAAA\*.*")

Do Until MyFile = ""

Name "C:\AAAA\" & MyFile As "C:\AAA\" & MyFile

MyFile = Dir

Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To copy all files and sub-folders recursively, use the following code:

```vb
Public Sub CopyDirectory(ByVal source As String, ByVal destination As String)
    Dim fso, file, folder As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'Delete existing folder
    If fso.FolderExists(destination) Then fso.DeleteFolder destination, True
    fso.CreateFolder destination
    For Each file in fso.GetFolder(source).files
        fso.CopyFile file.Path, destination & "\" & file.Name
    Next file
    For Each folder in fso.GetFolder(source).SubFolders
        CopyDirectory folder.Path, destination & "\" & folder.Name
    Next folder
End Sub
```

Use as following:

```
CopyFile "C:\Path To Source", "C:\Path to destination"
```

Note that the paths should **not** include a trailing directory separator (`\`).

Comment: Potentially how would you set it up so you could check to see if the file exists (latest rev?) in the destination folder before copying it?