# Type mismatch error when trying to copy files from one folder to another

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy all the files from a list to another folder in the cell next to it. I need this to loop through all the entries in a column. I modified the code I am using from [an old StackOverflow post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26241927/copying-files-from-one-folder-to-another-using-vba)

I can get it to work when I specifically put the paths instead of the variables but I keep getting a

> type mismatch error

on the first line in the loop `(Set fils = fso.GetFolder(filOrigin).Files)`. I am still new to loops so I likely didn't initialize it correctly or just totally messed it up in general.

```
Sub test()
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim fsoFiles As Files
Dim fil As File
Dim filOrigin As Range
Dim filDestination As Range
Dim rng As Range

Set fso = New FileSystemObject
Set filOrigin = Sheet1.Range("D2:D57")
Set filDestination = Sheet1.Range("E2:E57")

For Each rng In filOrigin
    Set fils = fso.GetFolder(filOrigin).Files
    For Each fil In fils
        fso.CopyFile filOrigin & "\*.*", filDestination
    Next fil
Next rng

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are passing in a `Range Object` instead of a `file path` to the `fso.GetFolder()` method which is causing the `type mismatch error`.

It looks like you are trying to do the following:

```
For Each rngO In filOrigin
    ForEach rngD In filDestination
        Set fils = fso.GetFolder(rngO.Value).Files
        For Each fil In fils
            fso.CopyFile rngO & "\*.*", rngD
        Next fil
    Next rngO
Next rngD

End Sub
```

`For Each rng In Range` means that rng is not the variable for the current position in the loop.

Comment: Thank you. After making those changes, I get an "Invalid Next control variable reference" error on the second to last line `Next rng`. I also get the same error when changing `Next rng` to `Next rngO` to be consistent with the for statement.

Comment: Ok so I changed the code to the following, and it works but not as intended,  Next fil
        Next rngD
    Next rngO  It copies the files in the path of D2 to all the paths in E2:E57. What I need it to do is copy the files from the path in D2 to the path in E2 and loop down like that.

Comment: I am getting a `subscript out of range` error at the `fso.CopyFile` line

Comment: I changed it back to the first way but changed the order of Next rng. This is my last try , if it doesnt work then I give up.